# Default union and structure alignment in C?

Tags: c, memory-alignment

What is the default alignment of global variables that are unions or structures. Are they guaranteed to be word-aligned? In particular when using GCC and SDCC.

In the code, is the function `f()` safe, or can it cause unaligned access? Is there a difference between 16-bit and 32-bit platforms?

```
#define ADDR_SIZE 8

typedef union {
   unsigned char u8[ADDR_SIZE];
} addr_t;

addr_t global_address;

void f(void) {
   uint32_t x = *((uint32_t *)&global_address) + *((uint32_t *)&global_address + 1);
}
```

Comment: Use pragmas to ensure pack of structs. See [HERE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html)

Comment: The term "Word" has no defined size/width, so it is useless here. The standard does not (cannot) impose any alignment.

Comment: Pragmas are not an option as the code must be "compiler independent" according to project's rules.

Comment: @kfx: So you cannot rely on any alignment or struct padding, etc. Sounds like an XY-problem. Please state what you want to achieve. Note that the casts invoke undefined behaviour and strict aliasing violations. General rule is not to cast unless you really need them **and** you know exactly what they do, including **all** implications!

Comment: My goal is to review this code and determine whether it is safe.

Comment: You cannot be sure about word size. You could thing to sizeof a pointer to see if the architecture is 8/16/32/64 bit, but some processors are technically for example 64-bit capable, but have modes to support "legacy code". An x86 (Intel/AMD's processors) can be 64-bit, but run code in 16- or 32-bit mode [and not even have enabled the 64-bit capability, in the case of a standard Windows XP installation for example.

Comment: In your case your code is always safe, because of uint32_t has always 32bit variable, and because of your union has a single member.

Comment: @LPs There are no `uint32_t` variables in the code. The global variable, which is an union, is casted to `uint32_t` type.

Comment: `global_address` is casted to `uint32_t *`

Comment: Why not actually have the union expose a `uint32_t` member so you're not doing the cast explicitly, and so the compiler knows with 100% certainty that the union must be aligned to support `uint32_t`? A `union` with only one member is rather silly.

Comment: There may other members depending on configuration `#defines`, it's just not relevant to the question.

Comment: Then you MUST post your real code....

Comment: This is the real code. I appreciate constructive comments, but let's not spam the discussion with not-so-relevant stuff if you cannot provide a well-referenced answer.

Comment: @kfx, I don't think that there is anything in the comments that is not relevant.

Comment: @JensGustedt This: _global_address is casted to `uint32_t *`_  in particular is false, therefore not relevant and misinformative... The **address** of the variable is casted to that.

Comment: @kfx, well, this is probably what they meant, and doing so is just erroneous, so it was relevant after all. And then, you asked people for help, didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specified the alignment requirements using for example `__attribute__((aligned(4)))`, you cannot guarantee the union to be aligned properly.

With careful global variables arrangement using `char` like here:

```
...
#define ADDR_SIZE 8

typedef union {
   unsigned char u8[ADDR_SIZE];
} addr_t;

addr_t global_address1;
char padd1;
addr_t global_address2;
addr_t global_address3;
...
```

You can [see](http://codepad.org/KmFozb7y) here the odd address:

```
0x804971d * &global_address1
0x8049714
0x8049715 * &global_address2
0x804970c
```

Attempting to access these address in some architectures with strict-alignment requirements will cause some misaligned access exception and halts the program. Other architectures that can handle misaligned access, at performance cost, will require at least two memory read cycles witch requires a number of CPU cycles to complete.

Comment: "Unless you specified the alignment requirements ... you cannot guarantee the union to be aligned properly." --. There are other ways that guarantee.

Comment: The code presented is not guaranteed to cause `global_address2` to be less than word-aligned.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the default alignment of global variables that are unions or structures.

It depends on the union members.

> Are they guaranteed to be word-aligned?

No.  (Assuming word is 4-byte).  Alignment requirements are complex.  Although they are rarely greater than the `sizeof(int)`, they may differ per each type.

---

In C11, by including a `max_align_t` object, the union will be aligned as needed to any type.

> `max_align_t` which is an object type whose alignment is as great as is supported by the implementation in all contexts; C11 §7.19 2

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef union {
   max_align_t dummy;
   unsigned char u8[ADDR_SIZE];
} addr_t;
```

[@Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021062/2410359) has good points about aliasing.   Just access the `uint32_t` from within the union.  Watch out for endian issues.

```
typedef union {
   unsigned char u8[ADDR_SIZE];
   uint32_t u32[ADDR_SIZE/sizeof(uint32_t)];
} addr_t;
```